# Can't choose to boot from USB?

Tags: boot, usb, bios

I have an Ubuntu setup on a USB, but the problem is I can't choose to boot from USB in BIOS. I can only choose my hard drive, DVD drive and flopy. I have  motherboard ASUS P5LD2

Comment: Probably best suited for SuperUser.com

Answer (score 2):

To boot from a USB Drive you need to connect the boot drive, then boot the computer to the BIOS.

Once in the BIOS, go to the "Boot" Tab and select the "Removeable Drives" option, make sure the "1st Drive" is set to the [USB DRIVE].
Then in the "Boot Device Priority" select the [USB DRIVE] as the "1st Boot Device", from there save settings and exit, the computer should boot from the USB assuming the USB drive is bootable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a pc with UEFI ? if yes in BIOS settings should be something called boot override and form there you can select your usb device. If this doesn't work look in your BIOS settings and enable legacy option.

Answer (score 0):

On ASUS P5LD2 your USB drive will (probably) be listed as a hard disk. Under boot options in BIOS there should be "hard drive (boot) priority", go there and move your USB drve to the top of the stack.